# Exception thrown while using ReplaceNULL function in SSIS

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, ssis

We are getting the following two errors from an SSIS package when doing a conditional split:

> Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.
> The "Find updated records" failed because error code 0xC0049067 occurred, and the error row disposition on "Find updated records.Outputs[same record]" specifies failure on error.
>
> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.
> The ProcessInput method on component "Find updated records" (76) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "Conditional Split Input" (77).  The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.

While troubleshooting this issue, I figured out that the below code in the condition of the conditional split is actually causing the error:

```
 (REPLACENULL(T1_from,"") == REPLACENULL(T2_from,"")) &&  (REPLACENULL(T2_to,"") == REPLACENULL(T2_to,""))
```

Where the types of the columns are the following:

- T1_from

  - Type: DateTime
  - DB Type: mySQL
  - Nullable: Yes
- T1_to

  - Type: DateTime
  - DB Type: mySQL
  - Nullable: Yes
- T2_from

  - Type: Date
  - DB Type: MS SQL
  - Nullable: Yes
- T2_to

  - Type: Date
  - DB Type: MS SQL
  - Nullable: Yes

While inspecting the data, we do have data looking like:

- T1_from: 2008-05-01 00:00:00.000
- T1_to: NULL
- T2_from: 5/1/2008
- T2_to: NULL

I strongly suspect that the exception is thrown when casting DateTime mySQL types from T1 in the REPLACENULL function but I can't figure out how to put it straight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try replacing nulls with a valid date to avoid comparing string vs. date, something like this:

```
(REPLACENULL(T1_from, (DT_DBTIMESTAMP)"1800-01-01") == REPLACENULL(T2_from,  (DT_DBTIMESTAMP)"1800-01-01")) &&  (REPLACENULL(T2_to, (DT_DBTIMESTAMP)"1800-01-01") == REPLACENULL(T2_to, (DT_DBTIMESTAMP)"1800-01-01"))
```